# Restarting dhcpd.conf failing

Tags: linux, dhcp, kickstart, isc-dhcpd

I am trying to setup a Kickstart server and when I am trying to restart the `dhcpd` server after having updated dhcpd.conf it is throwing a "failed" error.

I am installing the Kickstart server on a CentOS machine which is installed as a Virtual Machine on Oracle VirtualBox. I have bridged the network of the machine and the network of the virtual machine:

```
[root@server1 ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:56:0D:1A
          inet addr:192.168.1.29  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe56:d1a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:66790 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20761 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:73822713 (70.4 MiB)  TX bytes:2525478 (2.4 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:7083 (6.9 KiB)  TX bytes:7083 (6.9 KiB)
```

The dhcpd.conf file I'm trying to update:

```
[root@server1 ~]# vi /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
#   see /usr/share/doc/dhcp*/dhcpd.conf.sample
#   see 'man 5 dhcpd.conf'
#
class "PXE" {
    match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9) = "PXEClient";
    option vendor-class-identifier "PXEClient";
    vendor-option-space PXE;
    next-server 192.168.179.128;
    filename = "pxelinux.0";
}

server-identifier    192.168.179.128;

subnet 192.168.179.0  netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range dynamic-bootp 192.168.179.125  192.168.179.225;
#option routers 1.2.3.1;
#option broadcast-address 1.2.3.225;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
next-server 192.168.179.128;
filename "pxelinux.0";
}
```

Comment: Can I get help from any one?

Comment: You must find what is failing. Checking perhaps `journalctl` or http://howtonixnux.blogspot.pt/2008/01/checking-dhcp-logs.html